# OpenCV in Qt Creator : Cannot connect creator comm socket /tmp/qt_temp.T32147/stub-socket: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, ubuntu, opencv

I am using Ubuntu 12.04,OpenCV 2.4.1,qtcreator 2.4.1.
While I am trying to run my first OpenCV Program .I am facing the following issue

"Cannot connect creator comm socket /tmp/qt_temp.B32147/stub-socket: No such file or directory"

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks Neo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a solution to the problem but using QTCreater 2.6.0 resolved my problem . You can try the same.

They say the bug has been fixed but I don't know why its still not working!